# ping an ip address to determine if it uses AWS w/ Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I would like to use Ruby on Rails to ping a list of ip addresses to determine if it uses AWS EC2. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options. If you are on a linux system you can check the ip with `whois` command to see if its controlled by amazon.

AWS also publishes its IP lists. See here:  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=1701

Comment: +1 for the AWS public IP list.  I believe that is the only correct answer to this question, in light of the fact that discovering things about sites by probing them is often a violation of terms of service/terms of use agreements and generally not a good practice.